# Excel formula to convert groups of columns to a single row

Tags: excel-formula

I am struggling with a formula. I have tried a number of different calculations, but cannot seem to figure it out. Below is the data table

[image: Source Data]

What I am trying to achieve is below

[image: Required result]

Comment: So your question would be "Excel formula to convert groups of columns to a single column", correct?

Comment: If you only have 12 rows, you could transpose what you have and copy/paste a few times.

Answer (score 0):

if your source starts from A1 (not the row number, but date value), then put formulas in
Q1: `=INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1`
R1: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Q1,(MOD((ROW()-1),3))*5+1))`
S1: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Q1,(MOD((ROW()-1),3))*5+2))`
T1: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Q1,(MOD((ROW()-1),3))*5+3))`
U1: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Q1,(MOD((ROW()-1),3))*5+4))`

then select the 5 cells, and pull them down, then you get the results